# gamma function original euler proof

Tags: calculus

I am reading Euler original paper about the definition of the Gamma function, there is this formula:

$$\int_0^1 x^{e}(1-x)^{n}dx = \frac{1\cdot2\cdots \cdot n}{(e+1)(e+2)\cdots (e+n+1)}$$

I should expand $\ (1-x)^{n}$ by the binomial theorem, but I can't prove the result.

Could someone please help me?
Thank you

Comment: Maybe you could try induction on $n$?

Comment: Check out the [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) and the recurrence relation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beta function in Philip J. Davis׳ Essay](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3235364/beta-function-in-philip-j-davis-essay) or this? [Prove by induction that$ \int_{0}^{1} y^n(1-y)^r dy = \frac {n!}{(r+1)(r+2)...(r+n+1)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2297240)   (found [using Approach$0$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Cint_0%5E1%20x%5E%7Be%7D(1-x)%5E%7Bn%7Ddx%20%3D%20%5Cfrac%7B1%5Ccdot2%5Ccdots%20%5Ccdot%20n%7D%7B(e%2B1)(e%2B2)%5Ccdots%20(e%2Bn%2B1)%7D%24&p=1))